# Sencha 2.1.0 app is running successfully on emulator, but not launching on Android device

Tags: android, android-emulator, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have developed an app using Sencha Touch 2.1.0. My app is running successfully on the emulator, but when I try to launch on any device (I have tried four different devices), the default Sencha splash screen does not disappear and the app does not start working. The error I found from the log-cat is:

> 12-27 18:39:21.580: E/Web Console(23413): Uncaught Error: [Ext.Loader] Failed loading 'file:///android_asset/touch/src/event/Dispatcher.js', please verify that the file exists at file:///android_asset/touch/sencha-touch.js:8321
>   12-27 18:39:21.580: E/Web Console(23413): Uncaught Error: [Ext.Loader] Failed loading 'file:///android_asset/touch/src/event/publisher/Dom.js', please verify that the file exists at file:///android_asset/touch/sencha-touch.js:8321

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using a development build of the app where it loads in each class individually. I always use sencha's build tools, and build for "testing" or "production" before I go onto the device. The call to build for testing, if called from your project root is:

```
// this figures out all your project dependencies
sencha app resolve http://localhost/ref/to/your/project/index.html dependencies.json
// this will build your project for testing, which does not remove white 
// space or comments, and does not generate cache.manifest files for HTML5 caching 
sencha app build -e testing
```

The build destination directory is configured in the app.json file and will have some lines similar to:

```
"buildPaths": {
    "testing": "../builds/testing",
    "production": "../builds/production",
    "package": "../builds/package",
    "native": "../builds/native"
},
```

My development flow is to build in the browser, then build for "testing" when I need to test on the device. Here is my build.sh script, which I run from my application root. This script generates all my dependencies, builds for testing (based on my app.json buildPaths params), changes directory to a directory called "builds/android/" where I hold my android (phoneGap) project, then builds the project to the device I have attached via USB:

```
sencha app resolve http://localhost/careathand/front/mobile/dev/index.html dependencies.json
sencha app build -e testing

# build the application on the device with cordova
cd ../builds/android/
./cordova/debug
./cordova/log | grep Cordova
```

Now all I have to do is run the following command from my project root:

```
sh build.sh
```

A round about answer, but hopefully this helps streamline your dev process and ultimately fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sencha package run packager.json
```

seems not to work on Android 4.x.

Could you try this instead of?

```
$ sencha app build native
$ adb install build/[yourProject]/[yourAppName].apk
```